# Disable alt + codes such as alt + right-arrow for spades

Tags: windows

<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Numpad Right</kbd> gives me the spades character `♠`, which I do not want.  This happens in my browser, in putty, i.e. everywhere.

Is there a way to deactivate these codes?

Answer (score 5):

Use [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) with the script below to disable the shortcut key presses for all <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Numpad Keys</kbd> some of which generate special characters.

Note: In an AutoHotkey script, a `!` indicates <kbd>Alt</kbd>

```
; For Alt + key (with NumLock ON)
!Numpad0::
!Numpad1::
!Numpad2::
!Numpad3::
!Numpad4::
!Numpad5::
!Numpad6::
!Numpad7::
!Numpad8::
!Numpad9::
!NumpadDot::

; For Alt + key (with NumLock OFF)    
!NumpadIns::
!NumpadEnd::
!NumpadDown::
!NumpadPgDn::
!NumpadLeft::
!NumpadClear::
!NumpadRight::
!NumpadHome::
!NumpadUp::
!NumpadPgUp::
!NumpadDel::
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>NumpadRight</kbd> to work in the same way that <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Right</kbd> functions, remap the numpad items to their corresponding keys using Autohotkey.

```
; For Alt + key (with NumLock OFF)
NumpadIns::Ins
NumpadEnd::End
NumpadDown::Down
NumpadPgDn::PgDn
NumpadLeft::Left
NumpadRight::Right
NumpadHome::Home
NumpadUp::Up
NumpadPgUp::PgUp
NumpadDel::Del
```